# Building a django detailview and listview without using <int:pk>

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm building a django app that displays a database of employees and their salaries. It uses a postgres database. I'm struggling to figure out how to build a DetailView without using a primary key for the url. I think using a slug may be the solution but I'm not sure how to implement that and haven't had much luck searching online.

My Listview for the list of all companies:

```
class AllCompanies(FormMixin, generic.ListView):
template_name = 'AllCompanies.html'
form_class = SearchForm
model = bigdatabase
queryset = bigdatabase.objects.order_by().values('company').distinct()
context_object_name = 'companies'
```

Example Database snippet, bigdatabase:

```
Company EmployeeName Salary
Alpha   Jim          100000
Alpha   Tim          125000
Beta    Bim          90000
```

My list view displays all unique company names as intended. However, I'm not sure how to proceed and build a detailview to display more info on each unique company. I'd like to show things like number of employees, median salary, etc.

I've done something similar by building a detailview for employees, but that relied upon using their primary key in the url since each employee is unique. Since I have many entries for many companies in my database, how would I build a detailview and accompanying url structure to support that?

Any advice or pointers as to move this along would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a slugfield to your bigdatabase model. Try using the autoslugfield and set it to the company name like:

```
from django_extensions.db.fields import AutoSlugField

class bigdatabase(models.Model): 
company = Models.Charfield()
slug = models.AutoSlugField(populate_from=['company']
......
```

This makes sure you company name will automatically be translated for use in the url. E.g. when you have spaces in the company name, using str:company will translate in weird characters for the space. Using  in your url translates this to a -.

Naming your model field slug makes sure that your detailview get the slug field by default. See [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.slug_field).

Your views will then look something like:

```
class CompanyDetailView(DetailView):
model = bigdatabase 
template_name = '#path_to_template'
slug_url_kwarg = 'slug' # I believe this is done correctly by default but in case you change the field name.
```

In your url you can do something like mentioned above:

```
path('company/<slug>', views.CompanyDetailView.as_view())
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you! The bit in the model is what I think I was missing the most - couldn't quite wrap my hand around how i'd get a slug name out of it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that I understood correctly, but I thought you can use something like this:

```
path('company/<str:name>', views.company_detail_view)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation where I would like to display the user profile without using their `user_id` in the URL. So the URL would be `http://localhost:8000/accounts/profile/`

I was able to solve it by overriding the `get_queryset` and `get_object` methods in my `ProfileDetailView`. So now when the user visits their profile page it displays their profile without showing their ID in the url

```
class ProfileDetailView(DetailView, LoginRequiredMixin):
model = Profile
template_name = "account/profile.html"

def get_queryset(self):
    qs = super(ProfileDetailView, self).get_queryset()
    return qs.filter(user=self.request.user)

def get_object(self, queryset=None):
    if queryset is None:
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
    
    try:
        # Get the single item from the filtered queryset
        obj = queryset.get()
    except queryset.model.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404(
            ("No %(verbose_name)s found matching the query")
            % {"verbose_name": queryset.model._meta.verbose_name}
        )
    return obj
```